# Can Material UI and Bootstrap be used together?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking to build my first web application using React. I understand I can get component source codes from Material-UI and customize according to my need. However, while material ui only provide for components. Can I use bootstrap to get an HTML/CSS template to set up the structure of my webpage and incorporate react components using material-ui? I'm confused as to how to get the structure of the webpage with just material-ui alone. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would highly recommend not doing this. Pick a singular css framework and stick with it. You'll run into conflicting styles/classes.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you should implement the `material-ui` on your project. for example, start your project with `create-react-app` and then with the `material-ui` guides implement it on your project.

Then use the following code to change the theme to `twitter-bootstrap`:

```js
const BootstrapTextField = withStyles(({ palette, transitions, spacing }) =>
  createStyles({
    input: {
      '&:focus': {
        borderColor: palette.primary.main,
        boxShadow: `${fade(palette.primary.main, 0.25)} 0 0 0 0.2rem`,
      },
      backgroundColor: palette.common.white,
      border: '1px solid #ced4da',
      borderRadius: 4,
      fontFamily: [
        '-apple-system',
        'BlinkMacSystemFont',
        '"Segoe UI"',
        'Roboto',
        '"Helvetica Neue"',
        'Arial',
        'sans-serif',
        '"Apple Color Emoji"',
        '"Segoe UI Emoji"',
        '"Segoe UI Symbol"',
      ].join(','),
      fontSize: 16,
      padding: '10px 12px',
      position: 'relative',
      transition: transitions.create(['border-color', 'box-shadow']),
      width: '100%',
    },
    root: {
      'label + &': {
        marginTop: spacing(3),
      },
    },
  })
)(InputBase);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Bootstrap to setup your layout and incorporate components from any framework available. Example:

```
<div className="container">
    <Typography className="mt-3" variant="h5">
        Hello
    </Typography>
</div>
```

I've worked in a project that used Bootstrap classes and MUI components as well. I know that MUI has its own layout system, but I was already used to Bootstrap one and only wanted the components from MUI.